# Translation Help with 思うと and よかった思います

Tags: translation

> 日本語というものは、むずかしそうですが、私は、大学の時に、母に漢字を書かせられたりしていたので、今、思うと、たくさん勉強しておいて、よかった思います。

So far I have the following.

> The thing called the Japanese language seems difficult but when I was in college I was forced by my mother to write kanji so now if/when I think I study a lot in advance and think was well.

I am having an issue with `思うと` and `よかった思います`. I don't know what that `と` is doing with `思う` if it doesn't mean if/when. And I thought `思います` had to be proceeded with a `と`. Is this not the case and maybe it just means "I think it was good"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今思うと thinking back now, when I think back

When you see phrases like 思うと, 見ると, 振り返ると, 考えると etc., the following sentence is the content or result of the verb.

I think the と between よかった and 思います is necessary. There might be an error in your quote.

よかった is a kind of interjection. It is not just “good”, but “fortunate”. You are glad you have already studied it.

Comment: Sorry, but could you clarify "I think the と between よかった and 思います is necessary.". Are you saying the text Rachel G is quoting is in error, and there should be a `と` following `よかった`?

Comment: @DaveMG, Yes, I think it's an error. I've just checked [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/search_form), よかったと思 got found 398 results, よかった思 got 1 result.